# passing html div and variables to html5 canvas in animate cc

Tags: javascript, html, animate-cc

Hi everyone and thank you in advance for any light you can shine on this.

I have a birthday countdown in html using js, but I will love to pass that countdown to html5 canvas within animate cc (passing html div and variable values to animate cc)

not sure where to start. But my question is, do I need to start with :function 
handleComplete(evt) {
    exportRoot = new lib.Counter();

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
stage.addChild(exportRoot);
stage.update();

createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```